# XPath: Get all nodes containing a child node with a specific attribute using local-name()

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to get all `owl:NamedIndividual` nodes which have a child `rdf:type` with attribute `"some-attr"`.

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="some-text">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="some-attr"/>
        ...
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

The problem are prefixes (owl, rdf) - I am using local-name() function to resolve this in other cases but I don't know how to apply it in the case of attributes.

I've tried this way (problem lies around `@` I expect):

```
/*[local-name()='NamedIndividual'][local-name()='type'[local-name()='@resource'='some-attr']]/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@*[local-name() = 'resource' and . = 'some-attr']` selects attributes with local name being `resource` and the value being `some-attr`. So put that in step in your path expression:

```
/*[local-name()='NamedIndividual']
  [*[local-name()='type' and @*[local-name() = 'resource' and . = 'some-attr']]]
```

Comment: Perfect. Also learned a few things through this example, thanks.